# Query with two LEFT JOIN's is not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate

I am using PostgreSQL as my database and I need to write the query that returns:

- a `user_id` from 1st table
- sum of every row's `amount` from 2nd table (where `user_id` is the same as in the 1st table)
- sum of every row's `amount` from 3nd table (where `user_id` is the same as in the 1st table and the type is defined).

So I wrote this query with two LEFT JOINs, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
SELECT aff.user_id, COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) as total_bet, COALESCE(SUM(d.amount), 0) as total_deposit
FROM affiliate_guests aff
LEFT JOIN transfers t ON aff.user_id = t.user_id
LEFT JOIN deposits d ON aff.user_id = d.user_id AND d.type = 'deposit'
WHERE aff.code = 'code'
GROUP BY aff.user_id;
```

This query returns the wrong numbers for `total_bet` and `total_deposit` columns.

If I omit the second LEFT JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT aff.user_id, COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) as total_bet
FROM affiliate_guests aff
LEFT JOIN transfers t ON aff.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE aff.code = 'code'
GROUP BY aff.user_id;
```

everything works fine.

What can be the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your tables are defined:

```
CREATE TABLE affiliate_guests
(
    user_id serial not null primary key,
    code text
    -- etc.
) ;

CREATE TABLE transfers
(
    transfer_id serial not null primary key,
    user_id integer not null references affiliate_guests(user_id),
    amount numeric not null
    -- etc.
) ;

CREATE TABLE deposits
(
    deposit_id serial not null primary key,
    user_id integer not null references affiliate_guests(user_id),
    amount numeric not null,
    type text
    -- etc.
) ;
```

... and we populate them with some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO 
    affiliate_guests (user_id, code) 
VALUES
    (1, 'code') ;
INSERT INTO 
    transfers (user_id, amount) 
VALUES
    (1, 1000.00),
    (1, 2000.00),
    (1, 1234.00) ;

INSERT INTO deposits (user_id, amount, type) 
VALUES
    (1, 1000.00, 'deposit'),
    (1, 2345.00, 'ignoreit'),
    (1, 3456.00, 'ignoreit as well'),
    (1, 9999.00, 'deposit') ;
```

In order to understand why your query is not working as you expect, check first the result of executing your same query, but *without* `GROUP BY`, and changing your aggregates by just values (I've also added some extra ids for ease of interpretation):

```
SELECT 
    aff.user_id, transfer_id, t.amount AS t_amount, deposit_id, d.amount AS d_amount
FROM 
    affiliate_guests aff
    LEFT JOIN transfers t ON aff.user_id = t.user_id
    LEFT JOIN deposits d ON aff.user_id = d.user_id AND d.type = 'deposit'
WHERE
    aff.code = 'code' ;
```

This is what you'll get:

```
|---------+-------------+----------+------------+----------|
| user_id | transfer_id | t_amount | deposit_id | d_amount |
|---------+-------------+----------+------------+----------|
|    1    |      1      | 1000.00  |     1      | 1000.00  |
|---------+-------------+----------+------------+----------|
|    1    |      1      | 1000.00  |     4      | 9999.00  |
|---------+-------------+----------+------------+----------|
|    1    |      2      | 2000.00  |     1      | 1000.00  |
|---------+-------------+----------+------------+----------|
|    1    |      2      | 2000.00  |     4      | 9999.00  |
|---------+-------------+----------+------------+----------|
|    1    |      3      | 1234.00  |     1      | 1000.00  |
|---------+-------------+----------+------------+----------|
|    1    |      3      | 1234.00  |     4      | 9999.00  |
|---------+-------------+----------+------------+----------|
```

As there are not any relationship between your tables `t` and `d`, what you actually get is the `cartesian product` of both of them. You clearly see it because you have all possible combinations of `transfer_id` and `deposit_id`.

You need to make this by using `subquerys`, instead:

```
SELECT 
    aff.user_id, 
    coalesce( (SELECT sum(amount) 
                 FROM transfers t 
                WHERE t.user_id = aff.user_id), 0) AS total_bet,
    coalesce( (SELECT sum(amount) 
                 FROM deposits d 
                WHERE d.user_id = aff.user_id AND d.type='deposit'), 0) AS total_deposit
FROM 
    affiliate_guests aff
WHERE
    aff.code = 'code' ;
```

That will get you what you expect:

```
|---------+-----------+-----------|
| user_id | total_bet | total_bet |
|---------+-----------+-----------|
|    1    |  4234.00  | 10999.00  |
|---------+-----------+-----------|
```

See [Identifying and Eliminating the Dreaded Cartesian Product](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3901221/Identifying-and-Eliminating-the-Dreaded-Cartesian-Product.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a postgresql problem: when you do two left joins, you multiply the lines: every line in transfers will be joind with every line in deposits. In order to correctly JOIN you need only one record per transfers and deposit tables. Maybe your query could be done this way:

```
WITH
  tt AS (SELECT t.user_id, COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) as total_bet 
         FROM transfers t  
         GROUP BY t.user_id),
  td AS (SELECT d.user_id, COALESCE(SUM(d.amount), 0) as total_deposit 
         FROM deposits d 
         WHERE d.type = 'deposit' 
         GROUP BY d.user_id)
SELECT aff.user_id, total_bet, total_deposit
FROM affiliate_guests aff
LEFT JOIN tt ON aff.user_id = tt.user_id
LEFT JOIN td ON aff.user_id = td.user_id
WHERE aff.code = 'code';
```

Comment: @joanolo Both subqueries create a recordset with one record for every `user_id`. The left join should make it work when no transfers or deposits is available. Isn't it? Maybe the `COALESCE` should be moved to main `SELECT` from the subqueries.

Comment: @joanolo, users that don't have both transfers and deposits will be excluded if `LEFT JOINS` are replaced with `JOINS`

Comment: @eppesuig: my misunderstanding, you're right, it works as expected. (The query plan is rather complicated in Postgres, because PostgreSQL materializes `tt` and `td` when it could inline them)